# Using SQL Server with ASP.NET Core: data from tables not displaying to web app

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I've been trying to test a web app by displaying some data I have in my SQL Server database. Everything looks fine (e.g header / tables / buttons) however I don't see any data being displayed from those tables.

I've been trying to debug and checking what's wrong but everything seems right. Is there any way I can check whether the data is being read into the list which should contain all of the table data. (e.g print it to console to see whether any data is being populated)?

I've tried displaying simple text using HTML and that information is being displayed within the table, however whenever I run my SQL queries using C#, no data seems to be displayed. I'm not getting any errors which would indicate why it's not working.

Example of the C# code to run and extract SQL data:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Budget_Tracker_App.Pages.transactions
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<Transactions> listTransactions = new List<Transactions>();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=DAKI;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "SELECT CurrentDate, Amount, Category FROM January";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Transactions transactionsinfo = new Transactions();
                                transactionsinfo.CurrentDate = reader.GetString(0);
                                transactionsinfo.Amount = reader.GetFloat(1);
                                transactionsinfo.Category = reader.GetString(2);

                                listTransactions.Add(transactionsinfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class Transactions
    {
        public string? CurrentDate;
        public float Amount;
        public string? Category;
    }
}
```

edit: ive added the html code which displays the previosuly retrieved data into the web app

```
@page
@model Budget_Tracker_App.Pages.transactions.IndexModel
@{
}

<br>
<h2>Previous Transactions</h2>
<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='/January/Create'>New 
Transactions</a>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Current Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Action</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model.listTransactions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.CurrentDate</td>
            <td>@item.Amount</td>
            <td>@item.Category</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
                 href="/January/Edit?id=">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
                 href="/January/Delete?id=">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: _”Is there any way i can check wether the data is being read into the list which should contain all of the table data?”_ yes - use the debugger, set a breakpoint and look at the value

Comment: Could you please share your schema defination? What's your primary key for January table?In addition, if you execute this `SELECT CurrentDate, Amount, Category FROM January` query in your database are you geetting any result?

Comment: I hope you're not using a float for monetary values - its not designed for that.

Comment: Aside... `string?` seems redundant, consider changing those to `string`. If you're expecting `null` values consider changing `float` to `float?` and using appropriate `IsDBNull()` checks for all three columns.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes running that select query returns the appropiate data

Comment: @DaleK the reason i had initially opted for float was becuase i was using a program which incorporated python and sql server and float was my best option to account for cents. I'm now trying to display my sql data, would it be best to not use float when using ASP.NET?

Comment: Float is for scientific data, it doesn't store values accurately. You want decimal for money.